# Como añadir un cursor parpadeante a un efecto autotype

Tags: javascript, css, web

tengo un efecto de autotype para el cual intento que el cursor el cual esta representado como un borde parpadee, como cualquier cursor de texto. Lo intente pero no se como adaptarlo a mi codigo.

Dejo el código:

```js
/**Autotype */
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = "";
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + "</span>";

  var that = this;
  var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 3;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === "") {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("typewrite");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute("data-type");
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute("data-period");
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { font-size:50px;color:#fff; border-right: 0.08em solid #2bbc8a;}";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
.content a {
  color: #c9cacc;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 100% 6px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<a class="typewrite" data-period="1000" data-type='[ "python&nbsp;", "java&nbsp;", "flutter&nbsp;", "c#&nbsp;" ]'>
  <span class="wrap cursor"></span>
</a>
```

intente adaptarlo de esta forma pero nada, osea aqui no implemente la animacion ya que ni el borde se mostraba

```html
<span class="wrap cursor"></span>
```

```javascript
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  var css1 = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css1.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { color:#fff; }";
  css1.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .cursor { border-right: 0.08em solid #2bbc8a;}";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
  document.body.appendChild(css);
```

Tambien probe a crear un span con el simbolo `|` y aplicarle el efecto (para el cual funcionaria) su css seria :

```css
.anim-typewriter{
  animation: blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor{
  from{border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);}
  to{border-right-color: transparent;}
}
```

pero no se como adaptarlo a mi javascript, almenos de la forma que tengo ya hecho esto.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo agrega una [animación CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation) para hacer parpadear el "cursor", definiendo los `keyframes` para que se muestre el borde u oculte durante el mismo tiempo:

```
@keyframes blink-cursor {
    0% { border-right: 0.08em solid #2bbc8a; }
    50% { border-right: 0.08em solid #2bbc8a; }
    51% { border-right: 0.08em solid transparent; }
    100% { border-right: 0.08em solid transparent; }
}
```

Para aplicar la animación solo tienes que agregar la propiedad al elemento:

```
animation: blink-cursor 0.75s infinite;
```

Los parámetros son:

1. Nombre de la animación (keyframes)
2. Tiempo que tardará en ejecutarse la animación, ya sea en segundos (##s) o en milisegundos (##ms); solo ajusta de acuerdo a tus preferencias
3. Repeticiones; `infinite` para que se ejecute siempre

```js
/**Autotype */
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = "";
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + "</span>";

  var that = this;
  var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 3;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === "") {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("typewrite");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute("data-type");
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute("data-period");
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = `.typewrite > .wrap {
      font-size:50px;
      color:#fff;
      border-right: 0.08em solid #2bbc8a;
      animation: blink-cursor 0.75s infinite;
  }
  @keyframes blink-cursor {
      0% { border-right: 0.08em solid #2bbc8a; }
      50% { border-right: 0.08em solid #2bbc8a; }
      51% { border-right: 0.08em solid transparent; }
      100% { border-right: 0.08em solid transparent; }
  }`;
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
.content a {
  color: #c9cacc;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 100% 6px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<a class="typewrite" data-period="1000" data-type='[ "python&nbsp;", "java&nbsp;", "flutter&nbsp;", "c#&nbsp;" ]'>
  <span class="wrap cursor"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: gracias, tenia entonces el razonamiento correcto , solo que no se me hacia lio ya que la linea era un borde y no se, la verdad jajja pense que si añadia ahi la animacion iba a parpadear todo el texto